# PHP form action

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php connection to my database, I think i did most of the process right, but when I hit the submit button it just renders my actual php file on my screen.

Comment: Use PDO or MySQLi, the regular msyql_* functions are deprecated, also use prepared statements.

Comment: Also **paste code** not an image into your question

Comment: Do not use MySQL functions to communicate with your DB try to use PDOs. Do you have PHP and MySQL enabled on your Web server ?

Comment: paste your code instead of image

Comment: Also paste server config... thi is a server problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed (I can see it on source code of page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: half a meg of picture storage for that nonsense

Comment: sorry drew, won't happen again, can'y image if you were the one paying for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using a web server that supports `PHP`. It is rendering the code because `PHP` is not processing your code and renders it as text.

Try using another web server or install `PHP` on your current setup.

Also use `MySQLi` or `PDO` for your database part (it's safer and `mysql_*` is deprecated).